# set_value() in form - if return false (register fail)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Tried to make user input stay on text field if return fail
 **in View**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" value="<?php echo set_value('userName'); ?>"
```

**In Controller**

```
$Name = $this->input->post('userName');
```

But every time when fail ,it just show error code , it won't stay on the text field. Any idea on this ?

Comment: _"it just show error code"_ - What error and where?

Comment: can you share your validation controller code in which function you are doing it?

Comment: Your input name is "userName" but you try to get "user_name" and is return username string your set_value() function?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the error is that it does not stay on the text field after submit (and return false)

Comment: @TohidHabiby , Sorry , it was userName , changed in my first post

Answer (score 0):

try this on you controller,

```
$conf = [['field'=>'userName','label'=>'User Name','rules'=>'trim|required"']];
$this->form_validation->set_rules($conf); 
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s Required.');
if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('your_view');
    }
```

and on you view try this code,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" value="<?php echo set_value('userName');?>">
```

hopes this helps.